# iText - Clone existing content and add in same page

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I want to know if an existing content of a PDF can be cloned using iText. Basically I have a PDF in the below format:

**Without cloning the content**
[image]

I want to clone the content that is on the left side in the above PDF and want the result as per the below format.

**After cloning the content**
[image]

I am wondering if this is possible using iText PdfStamper class or any other class of iText?

**Updating the code with iText7**

```
public void clonePageContent(String dest) throws IOException {
    // Initialize PDF Document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

    // Original page
    PdfPage origPage = sourcePdf.getPage(1);

    // Original page size
    Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSize();
    PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);

    // N-up page
    PageSize nUpPageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(nUpPageSize);
    page.setRotation(90);
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

    // Scale page
    AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform
            .getScaleInstance(
                    nUpPageSize.getWidth() / orig.getWidth() / 2f,
                    nUpPageSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight() / 2f);
    canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);

    // Add pages to N-up page
    canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, orig.getHeight());
    canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, orig.getWidth(), orig.getHeight());

    pdf.close();
    sourcePdf.close();
}
```

With the above code, I am not able to produce the output as expected. Can someone throw some light as to what should be tweaked to get the above expected output?

Comment: Your code looks quite old, because the `PdfStamper` class no longer exists in the most recent version of iText (that is: version 7.1.2). What you are trying to achieve is very similar to something that is described in the jump-start tutorial: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the above link. I have taken the code from the tutorial, however using the above code, I am not able to achieve the above output. Would be great if you can point out the changes!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Can you help me with the above code? I am stuck at this point. I don't want to scale the original content, But copy paste the same content in the existing space

Comment: I don't have the time to write code for free for people I don't know, so please keep this a general question on Stack Overflow, and don't add my name in a comment in this context.

Answer (score 2):

After so many days of struggle, the below code helps in achieving the above output that I was expecting. Hope this might be helpful to someone, someday!
P.S: I am newbie to iText7.

```
public void clonePageContent(String dest) throws IOException {
        // Initialize PDF Document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

        // Original page
        PdfPage origPage = sourcePdf.getPage(1);

        // Original page size
        Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSize();
        PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
        //PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pageCopy,sourcePdf);


        // N-up page
        PageSize nUpPageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
        PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(nUpPageSize).setRotation(90);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

        // Scale page
        AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform
                .getScaleInstance(
                        page.getPageSize().getWidth() / orig.getWidth(), page.getPageSize().getHeight() / orig.getHeight()
                        );
        canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);

        System.out.println(page.getPageSize().getWidth());
        System.out.println(orig.getWidth());

        // Add pages to N-up page
        canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);
        canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 350f); //350f
        //canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, orig.getRight(), orig.getWidth());

        pdf.close();
        sourcePdf.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution here, it was exactly what I've been hunting for.